# Object release problem in iphone

Tags: iphone, object, error-handling, release

I am using navigation controller to move from one view to another ...
i have 3 views

arrangement in stack(navigation controller)is as follows

view1--------->view2----------->view3

on view3 i am loading a webview which show information based on user's current location...

the problem is that when i click backbutton on view3(during loading), my app crashes

my main problem is that the objects gets released when i press back navigation button..Which make an error..

i know that it can be fixed by making user's interaction OFF..

But the loading might take a long time in slow connections(because my app first gets location then send it to google and gets the name of location and then again send a web reguest to display some data) and during this long period user might frustrate ..

is there any alternative?
please help...i am just near to fixed my app..only this problem is left...

Comment: Can you please provide the full backtrace for the crash, as well as the code surrounding the crashpoint?  That'll help us diagnose the issue.

Comment: @Ryan--the error is
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use NSZombieEnabled option, to discover to which released object you trying to send message.

Double-click an executable in the Executables group of your Xcode project.
Click the Arguments tab.
In the "Variables to be set in the environment:" section, make a variable called "NSZombieEnabled" and set its value to "YES".

Comment: +1-after this here is the message  
  

2010-11-10 15:23:40.993 TotalLocksmith[8222:207] *** -[CarCenters respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7c59b20

here car center is my class

Comment: type of object (or the desired variable) that shouldn't be released is CarCenters.

Comment: If the CarCenters is type, go through stack of method calls and find variable which is CarCenters type.